# ReSharper suggests changing pattern matching code to object pattern

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper suggests changing the following code:

```
if (MyString is string myString)
{
    //...
}
```

to object pattern:

```
if (MyString is { } myString)
{
    //...
}
```

It says:

> The source expression is always of pattern's type, matches on all non-null values.

I have never seen this syntax before, and I cannot find any documentation of it. What is it and what does it do?

Comment: FWIW, I'm not even sure why ReSharper is suggesting this as an alternative, since it actually changes the logic. It's essentially saying: there's no point in the code you have, so why not try this code that does something entirely different, but at least would have a point. The salient issue here is that since `MyString` is a string, pattern matching it to string will always be true, and just results in an unnecessary additional variable. Pattern matching is for conditional casting. As string is always a string, so using it in pattern matching makes no sense.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have simplified the code in the question. I originally had something like `if(GetString() is string myString && myString != null)`, where the pattern matching saving the result of the method in a variable for later use. ReSharper told me the part `myString != null` was unnecessary since `is string myString` already ensures that `myString` is not null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`{}` stand for `not null`, but not invokes `!=` operator, so it's safe like `is null` operator which not invoke `==` operator.

There is lack of information about it. I found thread on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1944) about it. This is a preview feature for now i think.

Comment: Also some information here https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2624